# Schema Code cant be detected with Structure Data Testing Tool when using Google Tag Manager with DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, google-tag-manager

I have created a JSON-LD Websit Schema and attempted to add this code in a custom HTML container in Google Tag Manager.

I have setup a trigger for Pageviews and also changed it to DOM Ready when testing the Preview mode to see if it makes a difference.

After each change on the trigger I have proceeded to publish the changes. I did enable the option to Support Document.write.

The problem is that when I test the website with the Structured Data Testing tool it does not pick it up.

I have moved this code to the page header itself in DNN and it now picks it up.

Is there something DNN does which will prevent the Google Tag Manager from firing the code? It could perhaps be the trigger setup or the order it loads it.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "Our Company Name",
  "alternateName": "Other name",
  "url": "https://www.google.co.za",
  "potentialAction": {
  "@type": "SearchAction",
   "target": "https://www.google/Search-Result/search/{search_term_string}",
"query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
}
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "WholesaleStore",
"name": "Our Company Name",
"image": "www.http://ourcompany.com/",
"@id": "",
"url": "http://ourcompany.com/",
"telephone": "0000000",
"priceRange": "0",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"streetAddress": "",
"addressLocality": "",
"postalCode": "",
"addressCountry": "ZA"
},
"geo": {
"@type": "GeoCoordinates",
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0
},
"openingHoursSpecification": {
"@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
"dayOfWeek": [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday"
],
"opens": "08:00",
"closes": "17:00"
},
"sameAs": [
  "https://www.facebook.com/"      
 ]
 }
</script>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be anything that would have prevented GTM from doing what it needed.  DId you see any console errors when you tried the GTM way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all the schemas in the HTML tags inside your GTM to something like this:

```
<script>
  // Your regular schema data
  var jsonData = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "name": "Our Company Name",
    "alternateName": "Other name",
    "url": "https://www.google.co.za",
    "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "https://www.google/Search-Result/search/{search_term_string}",
      "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    }
  };
  // And then you append it to the head
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "application/ld+json";
  script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Somehow the way to inject as `<script type="application/ld+json">...` is no longer being recognized by the Structured Data Testing Tool, and now has to be injected programatically via JS.

Sources: [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/wFzBFwPDq1U), [2](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-structured-data-testing-tool-tag-manager-25811.html)